# Transform Data with Microsoft Spatial SQL

Tags: sql-server, coordinate-system

Is there a way to transform geographic data in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Specifically, I want to take Lat/Long data and convert it to a State Plane coordinate system.

Comment: Do you have the [Sql Server Spatial Tools](http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/) installed?

Answer (score 3):

Here's some sample Sql that does projection if you have the [Sql Server Tools](http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/) installed:

```
-- Project point and linestring using Albers Equal Area projection
declare @albers Projection
set @albers = Projection::AlbersEqualArea(0, 0, 0, 60)

select @albers.Project('POINT (45 30)').ToString()
select @albers.Unproject(@albers.Project('LINESTRING (10 0, 10 10)')).ToString()
select @albers.ToString()
```

Comment: That definitely looks helpful but it doesn't look like the supported projections listed will provide similar results to the state plane system.

Comment: What's the [SRID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Srid) of the state plane system you're using?

Comment: The SRID is 2228

Comment: I've never used it, but the readme with the sql tools says it supports lambert,  and [this page](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2228/html/) indicates 2228 is based on lambert, and lists the parameters.  So I think you'd be able to do a lambert projection and plug in those parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Have used this method

```
SELECT * FROM sys.spatial_reference_systems WHERE spatial_reference_id IN(4269,4326);
```

http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=sql2008_tut01

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered SQLCLR?  SQLCLR allows managed code to be hosted by, and run in the Microsoft SQL Server environment.  In simplest terms, you can create your own user defined function, stored procedure...etc in .NET, register it with the database, and call like any other SQL function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Essentially that is what the sql spatial tools are.