# What format is a location represented like this?

Tags: convert, coordinates, latitude-longitude, format

While converting an old system, I came across a position column with values in a format like this: `38RQT6410550656`

While I've never seen global positioning represented this way, [putting this in Google Maps will result in a correct location](https://www.google.com/#q=38RQT6410550656).  Without knowing what this format is called, I've been unable to find any information on this.

What format is this and how can I convert it to latitude and longitude (or get the location into a SQL Geography column)?

Comment: That looks like the [Military Grid Reference System (MGRS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_grid_reference_system).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The coordinates are in MGRS (Military Grid Reference System) which is a projected coordinate system.  Those coordinates give you an accuracy of 0.1 meters since there are 10 trailing digits. You can batch convert the coordinates in online websites like [this](http://www.earthpoint.us/BatchConvert.aspx)

The first 3 charcters are the  "grid zone desiganation" : 38R

[image]

the next two characters are the 100,000 meter square ID: UJ

the final 10 characters are the grid coordinates: x axis = 64105 y axis = 50656. Breakdown in image below.

[image]

I am not sure how you could convert to say Lat,Long from MGRS without the help on an online website. There is a Python module called [mgrs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mgrs) that could work if you know python.  I would also look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24712/use-ms-sql-server-to-convert-mgrs-to-lat-long) thread since it sounds similar to what you are looking for.  I am sure someone else has a better explination but I figured I would chime in.

update:

I just tested the python module and it worked. Here is a screenshot :
[image]

you will need [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org) and [Microsoft Visual C++ compiler for python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) for it to work.